# Call django.view function when dropping a box

Tags: jquery, django-views

I want to drag boxes (class draggable) between two containers (#UP and #Down).

Everytime the box is dropped, a request with information about this box (ID, Time of Drop) should be sent to my django.view and handled there with a function.

My HTML-Code looks like this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#Up" ).droppable();
        $( ".draggable" ).draggable({ revert: "invalid"});
        $( "#Down" ).droppable({drop: function( event, ui ) {
                        $.post("/127.0.0.1:8000/djangoproject/function/"}});
    });
 </script>
```

I try to call the URL, which is linked to my django.view function, in the function: "drop: function (event,ui) with $.post. However, it is not working.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Is it failing because of CSRF protection?

To do AJAX safely with CSRF, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax